# Intersection of a Set in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I started to study ZFC axioms recently, here the intersection of a set S is defined as ⋂A={x:∀y(y∈A→x∈y)} , Thus if S = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}} then ⋂s = {2, 3}, then by this definition what would be ⋂S for a set where S = {1,2,3} , would it be same as S or the empty set.

Comment: In ZFC, everything is a set including each of the natural numbers. $0=\{ \}$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{0,1\}$, $3=\{0,1,2\}$, ...  Yes, it seems strange to me as well. I prefer simply starting with Peano's Axioms. Then you avoid garbage theorems like $\cap \{1, 2,3\} = 1$.

Comment: I know that everything in ZFC is considered to be sets,now that i seen the answer of the question  ZFC sounds rather confusing...

Comment: It was so bad, that I had to devise my own simplified set theory axioms for software I developed to introduce students to the basic methods of proof. If you are interested, visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com. If you are really determined to learn ZFC theory and if you have the time, working through my tutorial might put you in the right frame of mind.

Comment: Ty, i will surely look at it,ZFC although seems hard but is very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is valid under the convention that every element of a set is a set.

So it can be applied on $S=\{1,2,3\}$ if $1$, $2$ and $3$ are recognized as sets.

Normally in settheory $1:=\{0\}$, $2:=\{0,1\}$ and $3:=\{0,1,2\}$ so that $\bigcap S=\{0\}=1$

Comment: On what far i have studied in ZFC a set consists of other sets so if we have a set S={1,2,3} then 1,2 and 3 are also sets thus 1,2 and 3 are also sets in this question, Ty for your reply

Comment: Can u help on a related question,I tried to understand it for a long time but still haven’t understood yet, basically if we have two sets p and q, where p={1,2,3} q={2,3,4} , then by axiom of pair we have a set say s with p and q its elements i.e s = {{1,2,3},{2,3,4}} and also ∩s = ∩{p,q} = {2,3}, my question is how do we get this result, now as 
∩s = {x : ∀ y( (y ∊  s) —> (x ∊ y) )} 
is defined like this, is p and q then viewed as the sets {{1} {2} {3}} and {{2} {3} {4}} respectively so that y ranges over them and if so also by above definition we have {1} ∊ S so why ∩s does not have {1}.

Comment: Let $p$ and $q$ be
sets and $s=\left\{ p,q\right\}$ is the pair. Definition $\cap s:=\left\{ x\mid\forall y\left[y\in s\implies x\in y\right]\right\} $
tells us that a set $x$ will be an element of $\cap s$ if and only
if it is an element of each element $y$ of $s$. So in this case
$x\in\cap\left\{ p,q\right\} $ iff $x\in p\wedge x\in q$ 
because $p$ and $q$ are the elements of $s$. Another notation for
$\cap\left\{ p,q\right\} $ is $p\cap q$. The $y$ in the definition
ranges over elements of $s$ taking values $p$ and $q$. If this is not an answer then post a new question.

Comment: That answer was just the one i was looking for, ty.

Answer (score 2):

If $1,2,3$ are atoms, that is just elements of $S$ and not sets on their own, the intersection will be empty.  Later you will probably use them as [Von Neumann ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), so $2=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ and the answer is different.